# Change the Price for All Products

Tags: magento-1.9, product, database, price, magento1.9.3

I am using Magento version 1.9.3.4 and having around 6000 products in my stores with varies categories. Now I need to change the product **Price by increasing 8%** for all products.

I have tried adding excel sheet and importing it and its taking very longer time to import.

Is there any other options to change the Price for all products at same time?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '8024M');

error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once './app/Mage.php';

umask(0);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');

foreach($collection as $product) {

    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
    $price = ($_product->getPrice() * 1.02);
    $_product->setPrice($price);
    $_product->save();

}
```